# How to make custom looping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to make looping like this with JavaScript ?

User Input : 126270

Output :

100000

20000

6000

200

70

0

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @KamilNaja I got confused with this, maybe there are some way ? I'll try with some array method but not work

Comment: This looks like homework, so I'll give a hint instead of an answer:  Each step of the output is a single digit from the input, followed by a number of zeros equal to the number of remaining digits in the input...

Comment: What is best methods to try that ? Im new in JavaScript, maybe array.map or something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use split it as a string and then map over the characters adding 0's based on the length of the string.

```js
 var input = "127000";
 
 console.log(input.split("").map((it, n) => it + "0".repeat(input.length - n - 1)).join("\n"))
```

Comment: Okey I'll try this way

Answer (score 0):

```js
input = document.getElementById('input');
calc = document.getElementById('calc');

calc.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log(calculate())})

function calculate() {
  var val = input.value
  var ret = []
  while(val) {
    const l = (""+val).length
    ret.push(Math.floor(val / Math.pow(10, l-1)) * Math.pow(10, l-1))
    val = val - Math.floor(val / Math.pow(10, l-1)) * Math.pow(10, l-1)
  }
  return ret
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" name="input" value="126270">
<button type="button" id="calc" name="calc">Calc()</button>
```